# Suppose f′′ continuous in [a,b] check:

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I am solving some exercises of calculation book, and I'm stuck in this exercise, and I do not know how to make this exercise....

Suppose $f''$ continuous in $[a,b]$ check:

$$
f(b) = f(a) + f'(a)(b-a) + \int_{a}^{b}(b-t)f''(t)dt
$$

Suppose $f'''$ continuous in $[a,b]$, Complete based on the previous question:
$$
f(b) = f(a) + f'(a)(b-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2}(b-a)^2 + \int_{a}^{b}\frac{(b-t)^2}{2}f'''(t)dt
$$

I appreciate if someone help me with this exercise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By parts:

$$\int_a^b(b-t)f''(t)dt=\left.(b-t)f'(t)\right|_a^b+\int_a^bf'(t)dt=(a-b)f'(a)+f(b)-f(a)$$

Now you try the other one.

Comment: thanks...
The other part is ??:
$$
\int_a^b \frac{(b-t)^2}{2}f'''(t)dt=\left.\frac{(b-t)^2}{2}f''(t)\right|_a^b+\int_{a}^{b} f''(t)dt = \frac{(a-b)^2}{2} f''(a) + f(b)-f(a)
$$

Comment: @Alexandre After the equality sign, the integral is missing a $\;(b-t)\;$ factor, since $$\left(\frac{(b-t)^2}2\right)'=-(b-t)$$